# Switching theme of my website

Tags: less, single-page-application, aurelia, theming

I wish to allow users to switch the entire color-scheme of my site with a buttonpress.

I have 2 separate .less files with the same global variables, but different colors. The problem seems quite simple.. "swap 1 .less file for the other". But how do I actually accomplish this?

Of course, I could alter the entire site element-by-element in the .js based on the state of a singleton, but that seems like a duct-tape-solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution by example: say you have a `div` element that you wish to color its background differently in each theme. Load both `.less` files and edit them like this (add the theme class to the `body` element that wraps the whole document):

**theme-1.less**

```
body.theme-1 {
    div.address {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

**theme-2.less**

```
body.theme-2 {
    div.address {
        background-color: fuchsia;
    }
}
```

Then provide a mechanism for the user to change the theme (e.g. drop-down menu). When the user selects from the menu - say for example changing from `theme-1` to `theme-2` - issue this JS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.replace("theme-1", "theme-2");
```

Generically you can do it in more than one way:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.replace(<currently-selected-theme>, <newly-selected-theme);
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove(<currently-selected-theme>).add(<newly-selected-theme>);
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for =)